# How to pass a proto binary directly in a gRPC call?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I already have the proto binary of a protobuf message object.

Right now to make a gRPC call I need to unmarshal it and send over the message object to the gRPC client(which will marshal the same object again), in the process wasting latency.

How can I avoid this by passing the binary to the client?

Comment: Define a new type with underlying type []byte that implements both [Message](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Message) and [Marshaler](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto#Marshaler) (by returning itself).

Answer (score 5):

This is possible using a custom codec. 
The custom codec can be defined as a

```
type StubbedCodec struct{}

func (cb StubbedCodec) Marshal(v interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    return v.([]byte), nil
}

func (cb StubbedCodec) Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) error {
    ba, _ := v.([]byte)

    for index, byte := range data {
        ba[index] = byte
    }
    return nil
}
```

Once we have this, we can pass the codec as a dial option as

```
grpc.Dial(grpcServer, grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock(), grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(grpc.ForceCodec(StubbedCodec{})))
```

This will force grpc to use your codec, which basically does nothing(as defined above).